# Kendo AutoComplete + AngularJS + array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui, dojo

I have to bind array of objects to Kendo AutoComplete + Angular. I have found an example of using the AutoComplete + Angular (it had "k-data-source" attribute), but the array consisted only strings. Another one I have found was about AutoComplete and array of objects.

Here http://dojo.telerik.com/ivUye is a link to my progress.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
<input id="i" kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countries" k-data-text-field="'Name'" />
```

i.e. Use `data-text-field` instead of of `data-text-field` and `"'Name'"` instead of `"Name"`.

Check you example modified here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/OkojA